# Можно ли просмотреть недошедшие до адресата письма?

Tags: centos, sendmail

На сайте функцией mail() PHP отправлялись письма. Сама функция возвращала true, но вот письма так и не ушли на почту. Письма эти очень важны, и хотелось бы как то их получить.

Возможно ли, что на сервере где-то есть логи отправленных писем?

Для отправки письма отправлялся POST-запрос на сервер, в переменных данного POST-запроса была вся необходимая информация для письма.

Есть ли где-то на сервере логи всех POST-запросов?

Нашел access.log, но там только дата запроса и IP адрес, но самих данных запроса там нету. Можно ли где-то найти более детальные логи, чтобы можно было восстановить утерянные письма?

Дистрибутив: CentOS

Comment: по умолчанию http-сервер, конечно, не сохраняет содержимое запросов. вам известно, как настроена почтовая система на машине, где выполнялся ваш php-код?

Comment: Увы, я в настройках серверов не очень разбираюсь, поэтому не знаю как настроен сервер и где и что он сохраняет. SSH доступ к серверу есть, пытаюсь найти логи писем

Comment: разумнее всего в вашем случае — обратиться к администратору сервера. потому что чёткого алгоритма, как всё это узнать, боюсь, я не смогу составить, а на интерактивное общение с пошаговыми вопросами-ответами у меня, к сожалению, времени нет. возможно, ценность писем достаточна для того, чтобы воспользоваться услугами какого-нибудь фрилансера.

Comment: чтоб вам было понятнее: возможны как минимум два варианта настройки почтового сервера: 1. он сам пытается отправить письма. 2. он отправляет письма другому smtp-серверу (т.н. smarthost-у). в первом варианте письма (если с момента их отправки прошло не много времени — ориентировочно порядка нескольких часов) скорее всего всё ещё находятся в mailqueue локального сервера. во втором случае (с той же оговоркой про время) они скорее всего находятся в mailqueue smarthost-а.

Comment: У нас скорее всего первый вариант, но с момента отправки писем, увы уже больше чем пару часов прошли, так как письмо вчера отправлялись.

Comment: мало вероятно что вы востановите старые письма, но во избежании дальнейших оказий, кои случаются с почтовыми службами, рекомендую ввести собственное логирование почтовых отправлений, то есть самостоятельно сохранять данные  POST  запроса  в файл (к примеру mail.log), или в бд, не забывайте про права доступа к файлу, и всё будет ОК)

Comment: *но с момента отправки писем, увы уже больше чем пару часов прошли, так как письмо вчера отправлялись.* в качестве ориентира я назвал нижний разумный предел. если используется какой-нибудь из дистрибутивных smtp-серверов с более или менее дефолтными настройками, то непринятые («отлупленные») письма будут удалены из очереди (если мне не изменяет память) где-то через неделю.

Answer (score 1):

возможны как минимум два варианта настройки почтового сервера:

1. он сам пытается отправить письма.
   в этом случае письма, если не были приняты «получающим» сервером, скорее всего всё ещё находятся в почтовой очереди (*mail queue*) локального сервера.

   просмотреть минимальную информацию о письмах (идентификатор, адресат, время нахождения в очереди и т.п.), содержащихся в очереди, можно командой:

   ```
   $ sudo mailq
   ```

   универсальной команды для получения большей информации по конкретному письму, увы, нет: зависит от реализации *smtp-сервера*.

   для *exim*, например:

   ```
   $ sudo exim -Mvb идентификатор
   ```

   для *postfix*, например:

   ```
   $ sudo postcat -q идентификатор
   ```
2. он переправляет письма другому *smtp*-серверу (т.н. *smarthost*-у).
   в этом случае они, скорее всего, находятся в почтовой очереди *smarthost*-а, и за их содержимым надо обращаться к владельцам этого *smarthost*-а.